# IPEDS variable for automatic admissions

Tags: collegescorecard, education

Some colleges and universities offer automatic admission to students who meet minimum criterion. For example, University of Texas offers automatic admissions to Texas students that are in some top percentile of their high school classes.

Is their an IPEDS field that indicates this type of assured admission?